# Angular Material2 SideNav onOpen on Close

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm making a webapplication using Angular 4 and material. I'm using the material "Sidenav" component. I'd like to trigger an event if the sidenav is opened or closed. By adding a function to the click property of the button the event is triggered. But if I close the sidenav by pressing escape or clicking somewhere outside the nav, the click event on the button is logically not working.

There are two properties for the sidenav called `onOpen` and `onClose` but I don't understand how to use them. Or are they even the right properties to achieve what I want to do?

Here a plunker for better understanding: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZPmhbFm1hbOUKYp1rV6J/

The result should be an alert with "World" if the sidenav is closed by not pressing the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen your plunker demo. You cannot use `onOpen` and `onClose` like that. Change your `md-sidenav` html to following:

```html
<md-sidenav class="example-sidenav" #sidenav mode="over" opened="false" 
            (open)="menufunction('SideNav Opened')"  
            (close)="menufunction('SideNav Closed')">
```

Here is a link to updated plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/96Hz4rZFJCuyNZDwEpGd?p=preview

Comment: For better understanding: this means that I can call the methond of any component by putting them in brackets. Or where in the documentation is it written that this component posseses an (open) and (close)?

Comment: if you see the documentation, you will fined `@Output('open') onOpen`, the parameter 'open' specifies the event. If you want to do the same in component.ts, you need to subscribe to the onOpen event like this: `this.sidenav.onOpen.subscribe(() => this.menufunction('Hello'));` I will personally prefer the approach I specified in the answer since its simple and does not involve getting the `@ViewChild('sidenav')`. Here is a link to documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

Comment: Just one more question (sry I'm quite new to angular), so there is a `@Output ('open-start') onOpenStart` property. This means that I can subscribe to it like this `this.sidenav.onOpenStart.subscribe(() => this.menufunction('Hello'));`. But can I also write (open-start)="menufunction('Hello');"?

Comment: sorry, I have not tried with `(open-start)="menufunction('Hello');"`, so I cannot comment how it works.

Answer (score 2):

`onOpen` and `onClose` are `@Output()` events emitted by your sidenav.

In order to use them you have to "store" your sidenav in a component's attribute :

```typescript
@ViewChild('sidenav')
public sidenav: MdSidenav;
```

and to subscribe to the event to do what you want to do when these events are emitted (I would advise to put this code in `ngOnInit()`) :

```typescript
this.sidenav.onOpen.subscribe(() => this.menufunction('Hello'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in event **openedChanged** which returns a boolean.

```
(openedChanged)=function($event)
```